# generate CoreML Encryption key when signed in with ANOTHER iCloud account

Tags: xcode, coreml

I have a mac where I am signed in with my own iCloud account. One of my projects is on a team to which I was granted access via a DIFFERENT apple id. I sign in to Xcode with that second account and everything works fine, I can see the apps in Organizer windows, upload archives, get distribution profiles and signing certificates etc. just fine.

Now I need to generate a CoreML encryption key (.mlmodelkey) file.

This is failing with the following error:

> Failed to Generate Encryption Key
>
> Sign in with your iCloud account in the System Preferences
> and retry.

Now I don't actually want to do that because my mac is setup with my iCloud account.

Is there a way to generate mlmodelkey without signing out of my other iCloud account on macOS?

Here's a screenshot of that error message:
[image: error]